# Use Select Element Without Dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, forms, stripe-payments

I currently have a pricing page on my website that uses the `<select>` and `<option>` html elements to let users select a pricing plan.

This is the code for the plan select dropdown:

```
<select name="plan" class="form-control" id="subscription-plan">
    @foreach ($plans as $key => $plan)
        <option value="{{ $key }}">{{ $plan }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

And here is what the form looks like:

[image]

I would like to add 2 cards containing the plan info that can be selected by the user and act the same way as the dropdown, except without it being a dropdown. The `id="subscription-plan"` is important because it sends the corresponding plan the user selects to the Stripe API, which bills the user's credit card for the amount set in Stripe. Does anyone know how I could achieve this?

I would like to do something like this (but without the dropdown styling):

```
<select name="plan" class="form-control" id="subscription-plan">
                @foreach ($plans as $key => $plan)
                    <option value="{{ $key }}">
                        <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Monthly</h5>
                                <h6 class="card-price text-center">$8.44<span class="period">/month</span></h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </option>
                @endforeach
            </select>
```

**UPDATE:**
I have tried this:

```
@foreach ($plans as $key => $plan)
        <div class="col-6">
            <label>
                <input type="radio" name="plan" value="{{ $key }}" class="card-input-element" id="subscription-plan">

                <div class="panel panel-default card-input">
                    <div class="panel-heading">{{ $plan }}</div>
                    <div class="panel-body">2 Memorials</div>
                </div>
            </label>
        </div>
    @endforeach
```

This code works and gives me the desired effect of having selectable cards, but the Stripe API now only receives the "monthly" plan even if the user submits their credit card details after selecting the "yearly" plan. This is because now both inputs have `id="subscription-plan"`.
[image]

Stripe JavaScript:

```
        const stripe = Stripe('{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}');
        const elements = stripe.elements();
        const cardElement = elements.create('card');
        cardElement.mount('#card-element');
        const cardHolderName = document.getElementById('card-holder-name');
        const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
        const clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;
        const plan = document.getElementById('subscription-plan').value;

        cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
            const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.handleCardSetup(
                clientSecret, cardElement, {
                    payment_method_data: {
                        billing_details: { name: cardHolderName.value }
                    }
                }
            );
            if (error) {
                // Display "error.message" to the user...
            } else {
                // The card has been verified successfully...
                console.log('handling success', setupIntent.payment_method);

                axios.post('subscribe',{
                    payment_method: setupIntent.payment_method,
                    plan : plan
                }).then((data)=>{
                    location.replace(data.data.success_url)
                });
            }
        });
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I have replaced `const plan = document.getElementById('subscription-plan').value;` with `var plan = document.querySelector('input[name="plan"]:checked').value;`. Now I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null` in console when I try to submit.

Comment: Are you setting a default `checked` item? It may be that nothing is set. Also make sure you update the value of `plan` whenever the user clicks the radio buttons, or re-collect it prior to submitting the request.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but it still wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the JavaScript side of this issue on my own. What I did was change `var plan = document.querySelector('input[name="plan"]:checked').value;` into just `var plan;`. Then, I added:
`$('input:radio').on('click', function(e) {
    plan = this.value;
});`.

Now, the form properly submits the correct plan based on the option the user selects to the Stripe API. This was a surprisingly difficult task for me to get this form to work without the use of the `<select>` and `<option>` elements. Here is the finished working code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-6">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="plan" value="monthly" class="card-input-element" checked="checked">

            <div class="panel panel-default card-input">
                <div class="panel-heading">Monthly</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <label>
            <input type="radio" name="plan" value="yearly" class="card-input-element">

            <div class="panel panel-default card-input">
                <div class="panel-heading">Yearly</div>
            </div>
        </label>
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        const stripe = Stripe('{{ env('STRIPE_KEY') }}');
        const elements = stripe.elements();
        const cardElement = elements.create('card');
        cardElement.mount('#card-element');
        const cardHolderName = document.getElementById('card-holder-name');
        const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
        const clientSecret = cardButton.dataset.secret;
        var plan;
        $('input:radio').on('click', function(e) {
            plan = this.value;
        });

        cardButton.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
            const { setupIntent, error } = await stripe.handleCardSetup(
                clientSecret, cardElement, {
                    payment_method_data: {
                        billing_details: { name: cardHolderName.value }
                    }
                }
            );
            if (error) {
                // Display "error.message" to the user...
            } else {
                // The card has been verified successfully...
                console.log('handling success', setupIntent.payment_method);

                axios.post('subscribe',{
                    payment_method: setupIntent.payment_method,
                    plan : plan
                }).then((data)=>{
                    location.replace(data.data.success_url)
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

More experienced programmers may have known how to achive this from the start, but I guess we all have to learn somehow. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

This should be doable by just iterating over the plans to create the cards and not using select at all. You could address the card selection with `onclick` handlers or by treating the cards as radio buttons sort of like you see here: https://codepen.io/stefanzweifel/pen/RNvGwz

Then instead of using the select value, you'd use the radio value.

Comment: This code solved the design aspect of my question. Thank you, my friend.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use `size` attribute to `select`

```html
<select name="plan" class="form-control" size=3 id="subscription-plan">
  <option value="1">
    <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Monthly</h5>
        <h6 class="card-price text-center">$8.44<span class="period">/month</span></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </option>

  <option value="2">
    <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Daily</h5>
        <h6 class="card-price text-center">$0.44<span class="period">/day</span></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </option>
  <option value="3">
    <div class="card mb-5 mb-lg-0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title text-muted text-uppercase text-center">Yearly</h5>
        <h6 class="card-price text-center">$80.44<span class="period">/year</span></h6>
      </div>
    </div>
  </option>
</select>
```